# replacing a string with SED

Tags: python, bash, sed

In a file (.py file) I have some classes with different name but some have common variables:

```
class myClass1:
  f1 = '512kB'
  f2 = 2
  f3 = 'something1'

class myClass2:
  f1 = '512kB'
  f2 = 6
  f3 = 'something2'
```

I want to write a bash script and use SED to replace some strings. The problem is I want to first find myClass2 and then replace `f1 = '512kB'` with `f1 = '1MB'`

If I use

```
sed -i 's/f1 = '512kB'/f1 = '1MB'/g' /path/to/file
```

it will replace that string for both classes.

Comment: What's your actual goal here? Are there thousands of copies of these classes or something? Why is this not just a single edit?

Comment: I want to automate the process. Otherwise I have to open each file and edit manually

Comment: +1 well written question

Comment: Ah, so there *are* a lot of these. Which leads to the natural question: why is the same value hardcoded in a ton of different places? As tripleee said, there are other ways, given that this is python code, not just text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 sed -i "/^class myClass2:/,/^class/s/f1 = '512kB'/f1 = '1MB'/" path/to/file.py
```

This assumes your class declarations are never indented.

However, given that this is Python, wouldn't it make more sense to write a simple subroutine to set the variable's value, rather than hard-code it?

Comment: that command just print the file.py in the terminal. The file itself has not been altered

Comment: Sorry, edited to add the missing `-i` ... and a remark about maybe doing this in Python instead.